# Calling a controller function in .net core react app

Tags: reactjs, .net-core

I have created a .net core project with reactJS, it has a Controller SampleDataController.cs in Controllers folder. how do i call it from my component's componentDidMount() ?

Comment: Please add some code, show us what you've done to research your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a controller action by doing an ajax call example:

```
componentDidMount() {
$.ajax({
        url: '/api/SampleDataController/MyAction',
        method: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json'
      }).then(data => {
          console.log(data);
      }).fail(() => {
            alert('error!');
      });
}
```

Comment: let me show you what i've done
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SilverPopTransactionAndMessage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
     componentDidMount() {
         fetch("https://localhost:1337/api/SampleDataController/MyAction").
             then(result => result.json())
             .then(data => {
                 console.log(data)
             })
    }
}

Comment: @vipinjoshi yes it can be done with as well `fetch`. You can read more about it on this [post](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/)

Comment: thanks guys i solved it , just added post type to call and removed "localhost:1337/"
sry for the silly mistake

Comment: @vipinjoshi he he he that happens. glad you made it. can you accepte my answer.

Comment: @vipinjoshi you welcome, you still need to tick the green button and vote up, thanks :)